# Desktop programming languages with the ability to interact deeply with other programs?

Tags: java, python, delphi, programming-languages, reverse-engineering

The title doesn't address my question entirely. I have always used Cheat Engine as a child and now as a junior programmer, I'm fascinated by it's ability to read an EXE's machine code so smoothly and can be able to modify it. People who don't know about it see this: [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_Engine) I have also used Resource Tuner to tweak some programs to my liking. I have tested many many minor disassemblers using PEiD and found that most of these types of programs were written in Delphi. When I searched this topic, I found minimal information, but I learned my best bets were Delphi or Python. Java was also mentioned. I use minimal desktop programming languages and I will still start learning. I just want to know what language has the best interaction with other software in the way above? If I would use any desktop language, I would use it to deeply interact with other software. Kind of like reverse engineering software. Note that a version of Cheat Engine was written in Delphi.

Thanks, Abdullah

Comment: How do you define *desktop language*?

Comment: Of the choices listed, only Delphi is really a suitable candidate, because it's the only one that builds as native code and has built-in functionality for low-level programming.  Python is primarily a scripting language, and Java is designed as a platform-independent VM language; neither one has inline assembly, pointers and pointer math, or various other features that are almost essential when working with programs at this level.

Comment: Programming languages designed to target desktop platforms.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's easy enough to do this in Python and Java

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Pointers and inline assembly?  If there's an easy way to do such things in either Python or Java, I've yet to see it...

Comment: @Mason Why do you need inline asm or pointers to disassemble code? Or modify existing code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Because disassembly isn't just code; it makes heavy use of metadata, especially in modern languages that have reflection/RTTI/whatever they call it in the language in question, and working with metadata tables without pointers is very difficult.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I don't buy that at all. And what about the inline asm?

Comment: Abdullah, Delphi is a great language - easy to learn, but very powerful.  For desktops (as in Windows desktop / UI?) it's unparalleled - even with WinForms and WPF etc there's still nothing as slickly wrapping the Windows UI as the VCL, the Delphi visual UI components. Plus it's a great language, decent community, easy to learn, etc. Python is also cool, and easy to learn and powerful too, but the UI side and native compiling (if that's important to you) will let you down.  Learn both, and you can even integrate Python in Delphi if you need to!

Comment: Since you are fluent in C++ that's the obvious choice for you

Comment: Are there any good Delphi-based IDEs other than Embarcadero Delphi?  I'm only 12 and more of an open-source developer. Can't afford that.

Comment: Sortof.  Some people use [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/), and open-source IDE using the open-source Free Pascal compiler.  It won't be as easy to use as Delphi, but it is free...

Comment: @DavidM Good, a version of Cheat Engine used Lazarus, but I did not want to try it until someone did recommend it.

Comment: Check out program transformation engines. These are designed literally to modify the source code of other programs, sometimes massively.  These have their own language for specifying how to write changes to be made. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation

Comment: @IraBaxter Great suggestion, but I was thinking of both learning a new desktop language, preferably one that can do what I asked above. Or did you mean each used a different programming languages, or did it use its custom language? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Each transformation engine provides a language (what does "desktop" mean?) for describing changes to source programs coded in arbitrary targeted languages.  In that sense, they can "deeply interact" with target programs; they can in fact make arbitrary changes to those target programs.   They aren't designed to fiddle with binaries, but with the right perspective (binary byte string as a language) they'd probably do just fine.

Comment: @IraBaxter Just what I'm looking for! And by the way, when I said 'desktop', I meant programming languages designed to target desktop platform. Not web-ones like JavaScript and PHP, while C++ and Delphi target desktop platforms.